# Can you search for multiple amenitys with one query with Overpass API

Tags: api

Is it possible to search for multiple amenitys with Overpass API. For example, hospital and doctor are a different amenity, can I search for both at the same time? Or does it have to be a different query?

I tried making a query with ["amenity=hospital, doctor"], but it didn't work.